# innerHTML img Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

The tcp server continues to forward the new image path.

The client continues to update the image through the path it receives.

*I think `.innerHTML = "<img` makes memory leak*

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const socket = io();
    socket.on('data', (msg)=>{
        document.getElementById('IMG').innerHTML = "<img src="+msg.imagePath + ">";
    });
</script>
```

This is my second plan.

**How can I keep changing the image without any memory leak?**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const socket = io();
    socket.on('data', (msg)=>{
        (function(){
            document.getElementById('IMG').innerHTML = "<img src="+msg.imagePath + ">";
        }());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change only the `src`:

```
document.querySelector('#IMG').setAttribute('src', msg.imagePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```js
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const socket = io();
    socket.on('data', (msg)=>{
        document.getElementById('IMG').setAttribute("src", msg.imagePath);
    });
</script>
```

This way, you'll update the src attribute of your `img` element.